# jquery not working on 'touch' (iPhone) device

Tags: jquery, forms, touch

I've got this jquery that clears the login form on click which works on iPhone

```
    $(document).on('click', '.error2', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
    });
```

This works fine on my iPhone...

This however -

```
    $(document).on('click', '.register-error', function() {
        $("span.register-error").remove();
        return false;
    });
```

does not work at all on removing all the spans on click. It does nothing.

Any ideas? Would this be due to CSS (by others)? Anyway to 'catch all' for touch on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery touch punch.
As the site describes. It's simple and works like a charm.

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 'click' event by 'touchend' event, it works for me